# Can I render an entity framework edmx file in the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edmx, edmx-designer

Ok I know it sounds nuts, but I have a project where I need to show the relationships between different tables in a web app for internal use. I know I can generate an edmx file on the fly, but how do I show it to the user in the browser? Thoughts?

Comment: Are you asking *how do I render and edmx file like visual studio does in a web browser*?

Comment: Yes, I want to basically do exactly what the designer does is doing in visual studio on a web page.

Comment: There are not tools nor examples of this that I know of.  You'll have to manually create this.

Answer (score 1):

edmx is just an xml. You can apply an xslt stylesheet to transform the edmx to html.